# How can I create a service for Desktop application using QT

Tags: qt, desktop-application, desktop

I am using QT 4.7.3. I do not have `QService in my QT.
Can anyone tell me how can I create the service for my desktop application?

Comment: What do you mean by you "are not having QTservice"? Do you mean you can't use it, or you're having problems including it?

Comment: when i am including the QtService it is not detecting the Header File

Comment: Have you included the QtService project? It doesn't come with the standard Qt installation.

Comment: @Merlin069 i didn't include QtService project.Where can i download the QtService project

Comment: Try here: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtservice